ahrefs Warnings about URLs in sitemap and redirects
Please forgive me if this is answered elsewhere but it's been doing my head in and I've been reading up about this for hours. I have a good health score for my website using ahrefs but there are 3 warnings that are still bugging me as I'd like to fix it if possible.
It seems my homepage URL is without the slash (example.com not example.com/) but in the sitemap.xml I think it is linking to the slash version then being redirected to the non slash version. So it's telling me that the homepage has no internal links to it and to add some. My site's navigation links use the non slash version for the homepage, all other URL's use the slash from what I can tell.  I'm so confused about all this.  If someone could have a quick look and point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. I don't want to go messing with permalinks and stuff I shouldn't be.
Here are some screenshots.  Also I don't understand where the www version is being redirected to the non www version? Maybe this is in .htaccess? Hopefully this is all ok and something I don't need to worry about as the site is very old now and seems to rank well so perhaps I'm just paranoid about these warnings from ahrefs.
My site is handcraftedtimber.com
I'm using Yoast SEO plugin





Thanks for your help.
Regards
Andrew

A few possibilities:

Have you configured ahrefs to just crawl the non-www version?  If they are crawling all subdomains, you'd expect them to hit the index and robots pages of the www version, and get those redirects.
External links may be pointing to the site's www address, so ahrefs may be reporting on these found pages.
You have some images hosted on the www version - search your site for links to the www version and update these, so you only use the non-www address.
Your www-to-non-www redirects aren't set up very well.  You should really be redirecting to the same page, ie https://example.com/robots.txt to https://www.example.com/robots.txt instead of redirecting everything to the homepage
Your homepage's canonical tag gives the forward slash URL as the canonical address

I wouldn't worry too much about any of these warnings SEO-wise. Unless you have moved to the non-www address, they all seem trivial.

Ok, I won't worry too much, thanks for your help. What would be the best way to search for and fix these links and images that are still hosted on the www version?  I had a look in my redirection plugin and couldn't find any robots.txt redirects in place.

You could probably just search in your posts and pages for "www." - or I personally use Xenu's Link Sleuth to find link issues.
The redirect is probably set in your htaccess file.  It should be one line to redirect all links to their equivalent non-www version, robots.txt was just an example.
